# sort word in 2nd array

Tags: javascript, sorting

*i have a 2nd array with that looks like this*

```
[['He', 2], ['saw', 1], ['her', 2], ['walking', 1], ['so', 1], ['asked', 1]]
```

i need to sort the array alphapticaly/by the number on the right

```
function sortText(arr, word) {
if(word)
    return arr.map(function(item) { return item[1]; }).sort();
}
```

*if the word parmeter is true then the array is sorted alphapticlly if it's false then the array is sorted by the numbers on the right *

```
the wanted result
 if(word==true)
[['He', 2], ['asked', 1], ['her', 2], ['saw', 1], ['so', 1], ['walking', 1]]
if(word==false)
[['saw', 1], ['walking', 1], ['so', 1], ['asked', 1], ['He', 2], ['her', 2]]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects#answer-979289

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a function that sort's the text in alphabetical order and takes into account capitalized words by lowerCase'ing everything.

```js
function sortText(arr, alphabetically) {
  if (alphabetically) {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a[0].toLowerCase() < b[0].toLowerCase()) return -1;
      if (a[0].toLowerCase() > b[0].toLowerCase()) return 1;
    });
  } else {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => {
      return a[1] - b[1]
    });
  }

}

let data = [
  ['He', 2],
  ['saw', 1],
  ['her', 2],
  ['walking', 1],
  ['so', 1],
  ['asked', 1]
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(sortText(data, true)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(sortText(data, false)))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
//WITH FIRST COLUMN
 arr = arr.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a[0] - b[0];
});


//WITH SECOND COLUMN
arr = arr.sort(function(a,b) {
return a[1] - b[1];
});
```

Use '>' instead of '-' if this doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You sort your array by:

```js
var arr = [['He', 2], ['saw', 1], ['her', 2], ['walking', 1], ['so', 1], ['asked', 1]];

function sortText(arr, wor) {
  arr.sort(([str1, nb1], [str2, nb2]) => wor ? (str1 > str2 ? 1 : -1) : nb1 - nb2)
}
 
sortText(arr, true)
console.log(arr);
sortText(arr, false);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could swap the sort order if needed:

```
  let wordFirst = true;

  arr.sort(([wordA, indexA], [wordB, indexB]) => {
    const byWord = wordA.localeCompare(wordB);
    const byIndex = indexA - indexB;

    return wordFirst ? byWord || byIndex : byIndex || byWord;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] > b[1];
})
```

or if you want stricter sorting:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] == b.[1] ? 0 : +(a[1] > b[1]) || -1;
})
```

There are really lots of ways to sort arrays like this and I hope this gave you a general idea!